# Creating another page and requiring a directory and checking if a specific file exists in that directory

Tags: inno-setup

I have Created a Inno Setup script using its wizard, now it's what I need, However, I want to create an additional page **after** the Installation Directory selection page, requiring another directory And if the user selected the directory, The "Next" Button should only enable when a specific file exists in that directory.

Can this be done in Inno Setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes it can be done.

---

You have to code the new page using [Pascal scripting](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptintro).

For a start:

- Use the [`CreateInputDirPage` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputdirpage) to create the new page.
- Use the [`NextButtonClick` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=NextButtonClick) to control, if the user is allowed to proceed.
- Use the [`FileExists` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_fileexists) to test, if the file exists.